# fireOnChange does not fire dynamics crm 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a javascript webresource in a crm2011 Contact form.
Under the form properties of the form, i added the `Form_onload()` function below to the OnLoad event handler.
When i debug it, i can see that the `Form_onload(`) method is being fired and executed.

However, when I try to edit the mobilePhone number and i click out of the field, i get nothing. When i debug, the breakpoint inside the `mobilephone_OnChange()` method is not hit, it simply does not do a thing.

```
function Form_onload()
{
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("mobilephone").fireOnChange();
}


function mobilephone_OnChange()
{
alert("fire away");
}
```

All what I want to do is, get the little alert inside the `mobilephone_OnChange()` function.

I seriously dont know what to do anymore. I've read tons of articles stating that `.fireOnChange()` will automatically wire up all OnChange events that are declared. However, this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("mobilephone").addOnChange(this.mobilephone_OnChange);
```

depending on how you've structured your js file, "this" maybe the name of your js class.

Also note that if you update the field programmatically in Javascript, the onChange event will not fire automatically.  (But can be via FireOnChange())

Comment: @Thousand you can also add the onchange event handler in the form UI. Did this not work for you or did you omit to add the handler as you did for the onload of the form? The onchange handler is a property of the form field as opposed to the onload which is a property of the form itself

Comment: @Daryl i tried doing it through the UI, but that didnt work for some reason. i just added it in the JS file in the On_load method and that worked fine :) thanks again

Comment: Thousand I think You intended to respond to @keerz.  I have found it is much faster development wise, to add the on change handler in the javascript rather then the Form UI.  This is especially true if you have multiple version of the form.

Comment: @Daryl good advice especially for multiple forms. I was really wondering if Thousand had tried via the UI. Wonder why it didn't work that way...

Answer (score 4):

I think you have this the wrong way round.

`fireOnChange` doesn't register a function on an on change event - it creates an event which will fire any registered function.

I think what you need to do is register mobilephone_OnChange() to the field, either via the UI or if you want to do it programmatically use [addOnChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_addOnChange).

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. when you say fireOnChange creates an event which will fire any registered function, how exactly does this work then? can you give a small example on how to do this or how this typically works? Also, if i use the addOnChange method and i load it in in the form_load, if i then exist the textfield, the method will be hit ?